# I have received a set with a piece which isn't a part of it and I cannot identify it

Tags: part-identification

I feel like I have seen this piece before, yet I also feel like it may not be a Lego piece. I am not sure! I have searched for Bricklink to no avail and it has no number or Lego number on.

[image: Lego piece]

Answer (score 10):

It looks like a [space gun](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3959), part 3959.

Comment: These pieces, in black, were also used as torches in some Pirates sets.